# Parsing a webpage JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display a particular webpage

https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation

but no matter what, my code only opens the home page of this website and not the link mentioned above. i tried the same code with many other websites, and it works fine. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NASA Meteorology </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
      function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {
          if (!site) {
              alert('No site was passed.');
              return false;
          }
          var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
          $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);
          function cbFunc(data) {
              if (data.results[0]) {
                  data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
                      window[callback](data);
              } else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
          }
      }
      $('#test').click(function(){
          var url = 'https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation';

          requestCrossDomain(url, 'someFunction');
      });
});

function someFunction(results){
    console.log(results);
    $('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(results);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="test">Submit</button>    
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

where am i going wrong? Any suggestions or hel would be appreciated.. thanks

Comment: note: you have 2 jquery library loaded into the page

Comment: *where am i going wrong?* - for a start, you're using `jquery.getJSON` and requesting `format=xml`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
&format=xml&callback=?
```

to

```
&format=json
```

And your $.getJSON will indeed get JSON

The result will be an object something like

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2016-02-10T12:26:11Z",
        "lang": "en-AU",
        "results": {
            "body": {
                // removed for brevity
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya I tried it. but still doesn't solve my problem. The link still opens only the homepage

Comment: @Sandy.Arv - I can see reams of data - 72 periods of data - and the disclaimer - and the last updated time - you just have to look at the data that is returned and you'll see that you get the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Try putting passing the params to ajax instead of attaching them to the url

```
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
          $.getJSON(yql,{q:'select * from html where url="' + site + '"',format:'json'},cbFunc);
          function cbFunc(data) {
              if (data.results[0]) {
                  data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
                      window[callback](data);
              } else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
          }
```

Comment: if i change the format from xml to json, the site itself doesnt load.. i.e., i am getting a blank response.. And i tried your solution with format xml, it still loads only the home page

Comment: why aren't you using iframes?

Comment: yup.. emcsg.com.. i am new to javascript.. i dont know iframes.. i will try studying it.. thanks for the suggestion